# How to debug a Python package in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

## Setup

I have the following tree structure in my project:

```
Cineaste/
├── cineaste/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── metadata_errors.py
│   ├── metadata.py
│   └── tests/
│       └── __init__.py
├── docs/
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

`metadata.py` imports `metadata_errors.py` with the expression:

```
from .metadata_errors.py import *
```

Thus setting a relative path to the module in the same directory (notice the dot prefix).

I can run `metadata.py` in the PyCharm 2016 editor just fine with the following configuration:

[image]

## Problem

However, **with this configuration I cannot debug `metadata.py`**. PyCharm returns the following error message (partial stack trace):

```
    from .metadata_errors import *
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

PyCharm debugger is being called like so:

```
/home/myself/.pyenv/versions/cineaste/bin/python /home/myself/bin/pycharm-2016.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --module --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52790 --file cineaste.metadata
```

## Question

How can I setup this project so that PyCharm is able to run and debug a file that makes relative imports?

Comment: Have you tried to specify `cineaste.metadata_errors` instead of relative import?

Comment: Is `cineaste` marked as a sources root?

Answer (score 25):

Today (PyCharm 2018.3) it is really easy but not obvious.
You can choose target to run: script name or module name by pressing the label "Script Path" in edit configuration window:

[image: Edit Configuration Window]

Comment: pycharm really hide the arrow well

Comment: Your suggestion in combination with the one from @pmneve works for me. (Pycharm 2020.2.3)

Comment: In the new PyCharm GUI the arrow is a drop-down button that says what is selected and is more visible.

Answer (score 3):

One of possible solutions could be to run your module through intermediate script which you'll run in debug mode.
E.g. test_runner.py:

```
import runpy
runpy.run_module('cineaste.metadata')
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also try removing the last node (/cineaste) from the Working Directory.  This configuration works (run and debug) for me (in Pycharm: 2017.2.2)

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion in combination with the one from @mikhail-lobanov works for me. (Pycharm 2020.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

In a pycharm session with a poetry virtual environment I use absolute import statements like:

```
from packtest.packtest import count_words
```

in all modules and submodules.

The packtest project file structure:

```
packtest
├── docs
│   └── _build
│       ├── doctrees
│       ├── html
│       └── jupyter_execute
├── htmlcov
├── src
│   └── packtest
│       ├── data
│       └── __pycache__
└── tests
    ├── __pycache__
    └── testfiles
```

In the src, packtest and data directories I put an empty `__init__.py` file.

While I am in the **root** packtest directory I run the tests with pytest:

```
pytest tests/
```

### **Debug and run** :

e.g. the packtest.plotting module

As in the answer from **@Mikhail Lobanov**

in PyCharm,  "Run" -> "Edit Configurations", I choose

`Module name: packtest.plotting`

Additionally, I make sure that the working directory is set to the root directory of my project (where the pyproject.toml file is located).

Now I can run, debug and test in the poetry environment without getting

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

which I got because I set the working directory to

```
packtest/src/packtest
```

instead of:

```
packtest
```

which led me to this thread...

The packtest example is derived from the excellent jupyter book "Python Packages"
by Tomas Beuzen & Tiffany Timbers: https://py-pkgs.org/

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest not using `*` since that can cause many problems in the future, two classes or methods being named the same etc.

Comment: This is good advice, but does not answer the OP's question.  This would have been more appropriate as a comment...just an FYI for future responses.